# Decide if the following functions are not continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Suppose $g(x)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$. Determine if the following functions are or are not cont. on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and explain.

a) $k(x) = \frac{x^2}{4 - (g(x))^2}$

b) $j(x) = \sqrt{e^{g(x)}}$

I'm not sure what values to plug in to test this since it is continuous for every value. Do you just plug in anything, like $0$ or $1$ to see the result? Seems like this would always be continuous though. Just based off of mental math, the first one looks continuous but the second one doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do we know anything about the relation $x \mapsto g(x)$ or just that $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

Comment: What do you know about $g(x)$?

Comment: That's the thing, the problem just says g(x) is cont. on (-∞, ∞). Decide if the following are/not cont...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(x) = \pm 2$, then there's a discontinuity in $k(x)$ due to the denominator being equal to $0$.

---

For $j(x)$, the exponential function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and its codomain is $\left(0, +\infty\right)$. The principle square root function defined over $\left[0,+\infty\right)$ is continuous so by the algebra of continuous functions, a continuous function composed with another continuous function is continuous.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So The denominator is equal to 0 when g(x) = 2 or g(x) = -2, how is this determined since we have 4 - [g(x)]^2?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how it's determined, but we can't divide by $0$, so the denominator being equal to $0$ would mean that $4-\left( g(x) \right)^2 = 0 \iff g(x) = \pm 2$. I hope this helps?

Comment: do you  mean from [g(x)] as floor function $\left \lfloor g(x)) \right \rfloor$ ?

Comment: (Not at all. Just different parentheses. I've edited them in case it's bothering you.)

Comment: Never mind. Duh, it's when 2 is squared or -2 is squared. Simple math haha. Thanks guys. Chose your answer @Khallil